# Mysql `using` syntax for multiple tables and one joining column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Instead of

`SELECT * FROM a, b, c
WHERE a.jid = b.jid AND b.jid = c.jid`

or

`SELECT * FROM a JOIN b USING(jid) JOIN c USING(jid)`

I'd like to use something like:

`SELECT * FROM a, b, c USING(jid)`

This may not seem like much of a convenience but when my query runs accross 4 tables and perhaps more, this could be a real helper.

I.e. there's one column that unites quite a few tables in my database. Is there a way to query multiple tables by naming that column only once?

Comment: How lazy are you? :-) Personally, I find USING confUSING, so I always right it out longhand.

Comment: The longhand version is error prone and can get quite out of hand when many long-named tables are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NATURAL JOIN` to automatically join the tables based on columns with the same name. However, you will need to make sure that `jid` will be the ONLY column with the same name, otherwise you will not get the results that you want.

> A NATURAL JOIN is a JOIN operation that creates an implicit join clause for you based on the common columns in the two tables being joined. Common columns are columns that have the same name in both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM a
NATURAL JOIN b
NATURAL JOIN c;
```

Comment: The actual command spelled out will give you an upvote and the green check mark.

Comment: There's not much to it, but I added an example.

Comment: I would have preferred to explicitly define the column being used to join rows but this will do. Thanks.